I have exported an HLL sketch from Snowflake, how can I estimate its count?
Snowflake exports its HLL sketches in dense and sparse format, depending on the size of the sketch:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-approximate-cardinality#dense-format

{
  "version" : 3,
  "precision" : 12,
  "dense" : [3,3,3,3,5,3,4,3,5,6,2,4,4,7,5,6,6,3,2,2,3,2,4,5,5,5,2,5,5,3,6,1,4,2,2,4,4,5,2,5,...,4,6,3]
}

{
  "version" : 3,
  "precision" : 12,
  "sparse" : {
    "indices": [1131,1241,1256,1864,2579,2699,3730],
    "maxLzCounts":[2,4,2,1,3,2,1]
  }
}

How can I transform these objects generated by HLL_EXPORT() into estimate counts with Python?

This plain Python code (it only uses math) can take these HLL sketches and output the estimate count.
For convenience I wrapped this Python code into a Snowflake UDF to compare the results from Python with Snowflake's native HLL estimations:
create or replace function hll_estimate_python(hll_sketch variant)
returns int
language python
runtime_version = '3.11'
handler = 'estimate_count'
as
$$
import math

def estimate_count(hll_sketch):   
    # Extract the precision and initialize variables
    precision = hll_sketch['precision']
    m = 2 ** precision  # Number of registers
    
    # Check if the sketch is in dense or sparse format and reconstruct the registers array accordingly
    if "dense" in hll_sketch:
        registers = hll_sketch['dense']
    elif "sparse" in hll_sketch:
        # Initialize all registers to 0 for sparse representation
        registers = [0] * m
        # Update the registers array based on the sparse representation
        for index, count in zip(hll_sketch['sparse']['indices'], hll_sketch['sparse']['maxLzCounts']):
            registers[index] = count
    else:
        raise ValueError("HLL sketch format not recognized.")
    
    # HyperLogLog constants
    alpha_m = {
        16: 0.673,
        32: 0.697,
        64: 0.709
    }.get(m, 0.7213 / (1 + 1.079 / m))
    
    # Sum of inverse powers of 2 for each register
    sum_inv_pow_2 = sum((2 ** -register for register in registers), 0.0)
    
    # Harmonic mean of the registers
    harmonic_mean = alpha_m * m * m / sum_inv_pow_2
    
    # Estimate the cardinality
    raw_estimate = harmonic_mean
    
    # Apply small range correction
    if raw_estimate <= 5/2 * m:
        V = registers.count(0)  # Count of registers still at initial value
        if V > 0:
            # Linear counting adjustment
            raw_estimate = m * math.log(m / V)
    
    # Apply large range correction
    if raw_estimate > (1/30) * 2**32:
        raw_estimate = -2**32 * math.log(1 - raw_estimate / 2**32)
    
    return int(raw_estimate)

$$;

This code works surprisingly well, at least with all the comparisons I ran:
select hll_estimate(hll_sketch) native_estimate
    , hll_estimate_python(hll_export(hll_sketch)) python_estimate
    , hll_export(hll_sketch) export
from github_stars_better
limit 100;


